# Select multiple widget

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am looking for a widget that looks like `<select multiple="multiple">` (it's expanded dropdown with a scroll) but you could only select one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean someting like this: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: he want to select only one option **You could only select one option.**

Comment: It turns out, select has a size attribute that defines a number of visible options and looks like multiple.